# How is the DefaultKafkaProducerFactory cache managed for transactions?

Tags: spring-kafka

In the spring kafka documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions

It mentions;

> Transactions are enabled by providing the DefaultKafkaProducerFactory with a transactionIdPrefix. In that case, instead of managing a single shared Producer, the factory maintains a cache of transactional producers. When the user calls close() on a producer, it is returned to the cache for reuse instead of actually being closed. The transactional.id property of each producer is transactionIdPrefix + n

- How is this cache configured e.g. producer pool size?
- Does it dynamically create a new producer when there isn't any available producers from the cache for the given transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the transaction is producer only and the `producerPerConsumerPartition` which is `true` by default (for consumer initiated transactions).

This property is to support `EOSMode.ALPHA` (or fallback to ALPHA when BETA is used but the broker is older than 2.5).

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#exactly-once) for more information about exactly once semantics.

When using `producerPerConsumerPartition=false` and for producer-only transactions, there is no limit to the cache size; new producers are created when the cache is empty, and returned to the cache when "closed".

Comment: For producerPerConsumerPartition=false and for producer-only transactions. 

How is the transactional.id suffix incremented is it when new producers are created and how is the cache emptied. To ensure ringfencing.

Comment: A new suffix is assigned when each producer is created; if you have multiple application instances, the `transactional.id` (prefix) must be unique on each instance. The class is cleared when the factory is destroyed (during application context shutdown) or when the factory's `reset()` method is called.